# How can I create SSH keys for containers from Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, ssh, ansible, dockerfile, ssh-keys

For my particular use case, I am trying to learn Ansible on a MBP with a M1 chip.  Since using VirtualBox is no longer possible, I want test Ansible playbooks through containers.

My idea is to set up two containers; one which will run the Ansible playbook (controller), and the other on which the Ansible playbook will run on (target).  One crucial feature that I need is the ability to SSH from controller node to the target node.

So far, I have been able to SSH into target node by following the setup below.  However, I would like to know how I can set up the SSH key creation and transfer through the Dockerfile?  Or, is there a way I can create the SSH keys locally, and attach them to the Dockerfile at the of its build?

**Creating a bridge network:**

```
docker network create localnet
```

**Running Two Different Containers (in different Terminal windows) in Interactive Mode**

```
docker container run --name controller --network localnet -it --rm alpine ash
docker container run --name target --network localnet -it --rm alpine ash
```

**From Within the Containers**

*target ash*

```
/ # apk update
/ # apk add openssh
/ # ssh-keygen -A
/ # /usr/sbin/sshd
```

*controller ash*

```
/ # apk update
/ # apk add openssh
/ # ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/root/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
```

I then manually copy the public key created on controller, and store it `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the target node.  This process allows me to SSH into the target node by running `ssh root@target` in the controller node.

How can I replicate this setup process using a Dockerfile?

Comment: Remember you can mount pre-configured SSH settings via `-v`, as in mount a pre-built `authorized_keys` into `~/.ssh`. This way you don't need to bake in keys into the image.

Comment: @tadman Do I not have to create the SSH keys inside the container?  Are SSH keys not host specific?

Comment: Ideally you don't have keys *in* the container image. You mount them *to* the container when you run the container, or you provide them as environment variables, secrets, etc. depending on how you're deploying. That is the container itself is sterile, you populate the required SSH config via deployment parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from your comment:
No, SSH keys are not host-specific.

The keys for public key authentification of a user are stored as simple plain-text encoded files in `~/.ssh/` (by default) and can simply be copied from one host to another.

The host keys which are used to authenticate the server are (by default for òpenssh`) stored in` /etc/ssh/`. They *should* by unique to a specific host and thus not be reused - but technically still can be by simply copying the files to another host.

I agree [with tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258094/how-can-i-create-ssh-keys-for-containers-from-dockerfile#comment134478097_76258094): the keys should not be included in the images but rather bind-mounted into the containers or [provided as a secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) at runtime. But it depends on your use case what is the best option here.

So the image would only need `openssh` to be installed and you could just bind-mount a pre-configured `authorized_keys` file into `~/.ssh/`:

```docker
FROM alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add openssh
```

```bash
docker build -t ansible-base .

# create ssh keys on the host
mkdir ./target_ssh_config/ ./controller_ssh_config/
ssh-keygen -f controller_ssh_config/id_rsa
cat controller_ssh_config/id_rsa.pub >> target_ssh_config/authorized_keys

# start target container with ssh config/keys from ./target_ssh_config/
docker container run -d --name target -v "$PWD/target_ssh_config/":/root/.ssh/ ansible-base ash -c 'ssh-keygen -A && /usr/bin/sshd -D'

# start interactive controller with ssh keys from ./controller_ssh_config/
docker container run --name controller -v "$PWD/controller_ssh_config/":/root/.ssh/ -it --rm ansible-base ash
```